# How to bind with provider which uses annotation value in Guice?

Tags: dependencies, guice, code-injection

Is there any way to bind with provider which interprets target's annotation value in Google Guice?

Example:

```
bind(Resource.class)
    .annotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class)
    .toProvider(new MyProvider<MyAnnotation, Resource>{
        public Resource get(MyAnnotation anno){
            return resolveResourceByAnnoValue(anno.value());
        }
    });
```

I want to initialize field of an Android Activity class by annotated binding.
It should have to take multiple resources by it's unique Id.

Original Way:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity{
    private TextView textView;
    private Button testButton;

    public void onAfterCreate(...){
        // set UI declaration resource.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        // initialize fields, it must be done after setting ui definition.
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        .... initialize other fields, hook them...

    ...
}
```

I want to bind UI and it's field in declarative way, not pragmatically likes above:

```
@ResourceID(R.layout.activity_test)
public class TestActivity extends InjectiveActivity{
    @ResourceID(R.id.textView) // Auto generated static resource id constant
    private TextView textView;

    @ResourceID(R.id.testButton)
    private Button testButton;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible as such.

If `@MyAnnotation` is a binding annotation, it will be compared using its `equals` method. `@MyAnnotation(5) Resource` will be bound to `@MyAnnotation(5) Resource`, and that will not match at all compared to `@MyAnnotation(6) Resource`. Check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704918/custom-guice-binding-annotations-with-parameters) for more. As in that answer, you could loop through your possible annotation values and bind each one individually, if you feel like it.

If `@MyAnnotation` isn't a binding annotation, you won't be able to access it at all from your provider. As mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027766/is-it-possible-to-inject-the-class-requesting-injection-using-guice), it is [a rejected feature](https://github.com/google/guice/issues/27) to add injection-site information to the provider or dependency itself.

Your best bet is to create an [`@Assisted` injection](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject) (or manual factory) to accept the parameter:

```
class MyConsumer {
  final Resource resource;
  @Inject MyConsumer(Resource.Factory resourceFactory) {
    int previouslyAnnotatedValue = 5;
    this.resource = resourceFactory.createWithValue(previouslyAnnotatedValue);
  }
}
```

You may also consider using [Custom Injections](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomInjections), which will let you use an arbitrary annotation *other than `@Inject`*, which may use runtime annotation values however you'd like.

Comment: Android SDK generates resource id constants, So I tried to inject actual resources into fields through `@MyAnnotation(resourceId)` rather than assign manually using `findViewById()`. Since I can't create resource instance manually because it must be resolved by Android application context, I can't use factory or assisted inject approach.

Anyway, Is there no way to interpret annotation value dynamically in provider? I can use looped comparable annotation which you said, But I have to iterate generated resource constants through Java reflection. It smells bed to me. :(

Comment: I think I should have to write own injection mechanism rather than using Google Guice. I'm so curious why Guice does not have binding configuration which fits my requirements.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "Since I can't create resource instance manually because it must be resolved by Android application context": You would still need your resource ID to pass as the parameter, right? Why wouldn't it be equally possible to implement your own one-method class (call it ResourceFactory) that returns an Android-created Resource?

Comment: Sorry for my insufficient explanation. I updated my question. I think factory still can't get information about inject target field.

Comment: True, though you could inject (say) a ResourceInjector you write, which could reflect across the class (resourceInjector.injectActivity(this)) and its fields looking for your annotation. You could then use a fake or mock ResourceInjector in tests.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in Scala (I like using Scala for prototyping, it's Java in a different dress after all) which I came up with after wondering about it myself in [Dynamic Google Juice injection depending on value of an annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36642511/dynamic-google-juice-injection-depending-on-value-of-an-annotation)

```
import java.lang.reflect.{Constructor, Parameter}
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference
import javax.inject.{Inject, Named, Provider}

import com.google.inject.matcher.Matchers
import com.google.inject.spi.ProvisionListener.ProvisionInvocation
import com.google.inject.{AbstractModule, Binder, Guice}
import com.google.inject.spi.{DependencyAndSource, ProviderInstanceBinding, ProvisionListener}
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import net.codingwell.scalaguice.InjectorExtensions._
import net.codingwell.scalaguice.ScalaModule

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object GuiceExperiments extends App {

  val injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule())

  val some = injector.instance[Some]

  println(some)

  some.go()
}

trait Some {
  def go(): Unit
}

class Impl @Inject()(
                    @Named("a.a.a") hello: String,
                    @Named("a.a.b") bello: String,
                    @Named("a.b.a") kello: String

                    ) extends Some {
  override def go() = {
    println(hello)
    println(bello)
    println(kello)
  }
}

abstract class DynamicProvider[T >: Null](binder: Binder) extends Provider[T] {

  private[this] val nextValue = new AtomicReference[T]

  binder.bindListener(Matchers.any(), new ProvisionListener {

    private[this] def tryProvide(target: DependencyAndSource): Unit = {
      val dependency = target.getDependency
      val injectionPoint = dependency.getInjectionPoint
      val parameterIndex = dependency.getParameterIndex

      injectionPoint.getMember match {
        case constructor: Constructor[_] =>
          val parameter = constructor.getParameters()(parameterIndex)
          nextValue.set(getFor(parameter))
      }
    }

    override def onProvision[V](provision: ProvisionInvocation[V]): Unit = {

      provision.getBinding match {
        case binding: ProviderInstanceBinding[_] if binding.getUserSuppliedProvider eq DynamicProvider.this =>
          provision.getDependencyChain.asScala.lastOption.foreach(tryProvide)
        case _ => ()
      }
    }
  })

  final override def get(): T = nextValue.getAndSet(null)

  def getFor(parameter: Parameter): T
}

class MyModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {

  override def configure(): Unit = {

    bind[Some].to[Impl]

    bind[String].annotatedWith[Named].toProvider(new DynamicProvider[String](binder) {
      override def getFor(parameter: Parameter): String = {
        if (parameter.isAnnotationPresent(classOf[Named])) {
          parameter.getAnnotation(classOf[Named]).value()
        } else {
          null
        }
      }
    })

  }

}
```

this only inserts the value of the `@Named`, but looks like it pretty damn works. so much for not possible.

Comment: Cool!  Do note that `.annotatedWith(Named.class)` is a somewhat deprecated Guice behaviour.  If I were you I wouldn't use the binding annotation to also get the value.

Comment: Also I don't think `AtomicReference` gives you the right semantics in the presence of threads, you need a `ThreadLocal`